# Iframe embedded with 100% height in a div has strange bottom-margin

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap an `iframe` element with `height 100%` and `width 100%` into a `div with fixed size`.

I tried it like this:

```
<div style="height: 410px; width: 480px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto;">
    <iframe src="" style="border: none; background: blue;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

With older doctypes it works perfectly, but as soon as I add the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` there is a disturbing scrollbar which makes it possible to move the whole `iframe` element up and down inside the surrounding div and if you scroll completely down there is a strange space, I can't explain.

When I remove the `overflow: auto;` property from the div-style it works too, but this can't be the solution.

The thing I don't understand is why there is this strange space/margin below the `iframe` element?

Here is a demo you can try yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/tmuecksch/b5jgn/

I tried it in Safari 7.0 and Firefox 23.0.1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `display:block` for your `iframe` element – without that, it is rendered as an inline box, and therefor space is left for the under-lengths of glyphs like g, p, f etc. of (hypothetical) text that might be displayed on the same line.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5jgn/2/

(`vertical-align:bottom` for the iframe would also work.)

Comment: Thank you. This is the most qualified answer. You are surprisingly right. I assumed iframe would have been rendered as if it was a block element. But as you said, it is rendered as inline box.

Answer (score 3):

```
iframe { vertical-align:bottom; }
```

or

```
iframe { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being `overflow:auto` allows the div to scroll if the inner content does not fit, and with 100% height it's causing the two styles to in a way conflict. If they didn't in theory the iframe could continue to expand.

Changing `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden` or even removing `overflow` would fix this problem

Comment: As I said, this is not an option. This does not explain this behavior and why it doesn't occur in older doctypes.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be an option as the iframe also has `overflow:auto` on by default. Also, setting the iframe to `display:block` should fix this for the html 5 doctype.

Comment: I'll add that setting `display:block` is a fix for most `height:100%` problems. Similar problems can occur with images.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is best to use the new attribute `seamless` from HTML5. You can read more about this and other new attributes [here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/2011/03/10/iframe-scrollbars-and-html5/). So, your code will look like this: `<iframe src="" class="" seamless="seamless" style="border: none; background: blue;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>`. Unfortunately, a pretty big problem is browser support for this attribute. However, browsers updated in 2013 should function. Let me now if that works! I test it in Opera 15.0 and Chrome 29 and it works.